# How can I do an ASP.NET background service which always runs in background?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a very interesting problem. I have a web site with asp.net . What i need is independent service which should be always running in background. For example i could do some db operations in specific dates. And no need to page request from somebody. Just independent. Which method i should follow?
Every idea would be happily accepted. Thanks

Comment: you can use Global.asax file with timer

Comment: i did the way in a project where i needed to call a method after every 1 minute

Comment: or you can make a windows service which will be running on server

Comment: If you are just looking to do scheduled tasks in a SQL Server DB, you could use a SQL Server Agent Job for that.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135739(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement another application. You need no request, just perform some task - then use desktop application this time. If you need to provide UI then use WPF or Win Forms, if only perform some task then use just console application. To run it at specific time you might use windows task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You need an external application, either a service/program running on your PC/the server, or on the network of the hosting provider.
For ideas, if you want your website to provide scheduling etc, windows Azure provides a scheduling service that can call a web address (yourwebsite.com/runscheduler for instance) at given intervals. When this web address is called your website can then act on it of course by doing some business logic.

Comment: Thanks for answer I think i will implement another application

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you take a look at the [Revalee](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com) open source project.

Revalee is a service that allows you to schedule web callbacks to your web application. In your case, you would schedule a callback that would perfrom specific database operations specific time. Revalee works very well with tasks that are discrete transactional actions, like updating some database values or sending an automated email message (read: not long running). The code to perform your action would all reside within your app.

To use Revalee, you would:

1. Install the Revalee Service, a Windows Service, on your server. The Windows Service is available in the source code (which you would compile yourself) or in a precompiled version available at the [Revalee website](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com).
2. Use the Revalee client library in your Visual Studio project. (There is an MVC-specific version too.) The client library is available in the source code (which, again, you would compile yourself) or in a precompiled version available via [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Revalee.Client/).
3. You would register a future callback when your code calls the `ScheduleDbOperation()` method (this example is assuming that you need your action to run 12 hours from now).

   ```
   private void ScheduleDbOperation()
   {
       DateTimeOffset callbackTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(12.0);

       // The callback should be in 12 hours from now
       Uri callbackUrl = new Uri(string.Format("http://mywebapp.com/DbOperation.aspx"));

       // Register the callback request with the Revalee service
       RevaleeRegistrar.ScheduleCallback(callbackTime, callbackUrl);
   }
   ```
4. When Revalee calls your application back, your app would perform whatever action you have coded it to do. You do this by adding the following method call (`DbOperation()`) to your `DbOperation.aspx` page handler, à la:

   ```
   private void DbOperation()
   {
       // TODO Lookup the job information and execute the database operation
       // ...

       return;
   }
   ```

I hope this helps.

Note: The code example above uses a synchronous version of `ScheduleCallback()`, the Revalee client library also supports asynchronous calls à la:

```
RevaleeRegistrar.ScheduleCallbackAsync(callbackTime, callbackUrl);
```

In case it was not clear above, the Revalee Service is not an external 3rd party online scheduler service, but instead a Windows Service that you install *and* fully control on your own network. It resides and runs on a server of your own choosing, most likely your web server (but this is not a requirement), where it can receive callback registration requests from your ASP.NET application.

<sub>**Disclaimer:** I was one of the developers involved with the Revalee project. To be clear, however, Revalee is free, open source software. The source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/SageAnalytic/Revalee).</sub>